# Having an issue with form inputs on a javascript schedule

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble with a scheduling POC I've been working on for my company.  basically it consists of a bunch of radio buttons in a table with selections for each shift, and a dropdown for the employee.  the issue i'm having is, the radio buttons don't seem to be outputting correctly.  can someone take a look and see what i'm missing?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<script language="Javascript">
function download(filename, text) {
var pom = document.createElement('a');
pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 

encodeURIComponent(text));
pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

pom.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(pom);

pom.click();

document.body.removeChild(pom);
}

function addTextTXT()
{
document.addtext.name.value = document.addtext.name.value + ".txt"
}

function my_curr_date() {      
var currentDate = new Date()
var day = currentDate.getDate();
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
var my_date = month+"-"+day+"-"+year;
document.getElementById("dateField").value=my_date;    
}
</script> </head>
<body onload="return my_curr_date();">
<div style="text-align: center;">Today's Date is:
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input name="dateField" id="dateField" value="" 
type="text"><span

    style="font-family: Arial;"> </span></div>
<form name="addtext" onsubmit="download(this['uid'].value, this['1'].value+this['2'].value+this['3'].value+this['4'].value+this['5'].value+this['6'].value+this['7'].value+this['8'].value+this['9'].value+this['10'].value+this['11'].value+this['12'].value+this['13'].value+this['14'].value+this['15'].value+this['16'].value+this['17'].value+this['18'].value+this['19'].value+this['20'].value+this['21'].value+this['22'].value+this['23'].value+this['24'].value+this['25'].value+this['26'].value+this['27'].value+this['28'].value+this['29'].value+this['30'].value+this['31'].value)">
  <p><br>
  </p>
  <table style="width: 707px; height: 550px; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"

    border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span style="font-family: Arial;">Sunday</span></td>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>Tuesday</td>
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td>Thursday</td>
        <td style="height: 27.5px;">Friday</td>
        <td>Saturday</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 84.55px;"><br>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 82.7px;"><br>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 91.483px;"><br>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 103.05px;"><br>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 97.9px;"><br>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 101.267px;">
          <div style="text-align: center;">1st</div>
          <input name="1" value="3-9," id="1st" type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="1" value="5-9," id="1st" type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="1" value="off," checked="checked" id="1st" type="radio">Off</td>
        <td style="width: 100.567px;">
          <div style="text-align: center;">2nd</div>
          <input name="2" value="10-5," type="radio">10-5<br>
          <br>
          <input name="2" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">3rd</div>
          <input name="3" value="11-6," type="radio">11-6<br>
          <br>
          <input name="3" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">4th</div>
          <input name="4" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="4" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="4" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off <br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">5th</div>
          <input name="5" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="5" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="5" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">6th</div>
          <input name="6" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="6" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="6" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">7th</div>
          <input name="7" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="7" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="7" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">8th</div>
          <input name="8" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="8" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="8" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
          <div style="text-align: center;"><br>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td style="margin-left: 27px;">
          <div style="text-align: center;">9th</div>
          <input name="9" value="10-5," type="radio">10-5<br>
          <br>
          <input name="9" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">10th</div>
          <input name="10" value="11-6," type="radio">11-6<br>
          <br>
          <input name="10" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">11th</div>
          <input name="11" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="11" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="11" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">12th</div>
          <input name="12" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="12" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="12" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">13th</div>
          <input name="13" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="13" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="13" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">14th</div>
          <input name="14" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="14" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="14" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">15th</div>
          <input name="15" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="15" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="15" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">16th</div>
          <input name="16" value="10-5," type="radio">10-5<br>
          <br>
          <input name="16" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">17th</div>
          <input name="17" value="11-6," type="radio">11-6<br>
          <br>
          <input name="17" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">18th</div>
          <input name="18" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="18" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="18" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">19th</div>
          <input name="19" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="19" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="19" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">20th</div>
          <input name="20" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="20" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="20" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">21st</div>
          <input name="21" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="21" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="21" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">22nd</div>
          <input name="22" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="22" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="22" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">23rd</div>
          <input name="23" value="10-5," type="radio">10-5<br>
          <br>
          <input name="23" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">24th</div>
          <input name="24" value="11-6," type="radio">11-6<br>
          <br>
          <input name="24" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">25th</div>
          <input name="25" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="25" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="25" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">26th</div>
          <input name="26" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="26" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="26" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">27th</div>
          <input name="27" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="27" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="27" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">28th</div>
          <input name="28" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="28" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="28" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">29th</div>
          <input name="29" value="3-9," type="radio">3-9<br>
          <input name="29" value="5-9," type="radio">5-9<br>
          <input name="29" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">30th</div>
          <input name="30" value="10-5," type="radio">10-5<br>
          <br>
          <input name="30" value="off," checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="text-align: center;">31st</div>
          <input name="31" value="11-6" type="radio">11-6<br>
          <br>
          <input name="31" value="off" checked="checked" type="radio">Off<br>
        </td>
        <td><br>
        </td>
        <td><br>
        </td>
        <td><br>
        </td>
        <td><br>
        </td>
        <td><br>
        </td>
        <td><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div style="text-align: center;"><big>
      <p><span style="font-family: Arial;"><br>
          <select name="uid">
            <option value="5173">JOHNSON, KATHLEEN M.</option>
            <option value="5177">LEWIS, KEVIN R.</option>
            <option value="5186">PAINE, CINDI</option>
            <option value="5195">WHITAKER, JESSE J.</option>
            <option value="5370">CRUM, BRYAN K.</option>
            <option value="5406">JACKS, KEVIN</option>
            <option value="5862">BUTLER, SHERYL L.</option>
            <option value="5865">LUIS, CINDY L.</option>
            <option value="5895">KAWAGUCHI, CHISATO C.</option>
            <option value="6036">GUERTLER, GARY M.</option>
            <option value="6037">NELSEN, CONNIE R.</option>
            <option value="6084">KIRSCHBAUM, LINDA M.</option>
            <option value="6204">DUNLAVY, JOHN H.</option>
            <option value="6496">COURTNEY, MORRIS D.</option>
            <option value="6499">HENDERSON, THOMAS</option>
            <option value="6548">NELSON, DEBRA G.</option>
            <option value="6621">RIGGS, JUDITH A.</option>
            <option value="6689">BUTLER, BILLIE M.</option>
            <option value="6690">CASEM, MARY K.</option>
            <option value="7033">MCGRIFF, MICHELLE R.</option>
            <option value="7056">BUTLER, SHANNON P.</option>
            <option value="7060">ALLEN, SANDRA L.</option>
            <option value="7093">PERKINS, SHIRLEEN R.</option>
            <option value="7134">MAZOW, JOSHUA</option>
            <option value="7145">HANLEY, KIMBERLY Y.</option>
            <option value="7209">HARLOW, CONNIE R.</option>
            <option value="7277">AMES, DAWN M.</option>
            <option value="7283">YOUNG, DIAMOND P.</option>
            <option value="7354">MACMILLAN, ANN V.</option>
            <option value="7483">CHAFFEE, RAEANNE M.</option>
            <option value="7528">WELDEN, MATTHEW</option>
            <option value="7609">GERYAN, RICHARD D.</option>
            <option value="7613">NOSRATI, MEHDI</option>
            <option value="7614">REYES, DONALD D.</option>
            <option value="7627">PRISCO, JOSEPH A.</option>
            <option value="7733">CHAMBERS, SANDRA C.</option>
            <option value="7827">CLEMONS, SYBIL R.</option>
            <option value="7879">MCFALL, PATRICIA M.</option>
            <option value="7891">DEVRIEZE, JOSEPH F.</option>
            <option value="7914">FREES, SUSAN A.</option>
            <option value="7954">ADAMS, KENA C.</option>
            <option value="7983">FARKAS, IVETT</option>
            <option value="7994">WEISNER, SHANE T.</option>
            <option value="8013">DUGUID, CHERYL T.</option>
            <option value="8029">YODER, CYNTHIA L.</option>
            <option value="8073">BALDERAS, CHRISTINA L.</option>
            <option value="8075">HAW JR, EDWIN H.</option>
            <option value="8106">GLORE JR., GEORGE S.</option>
            <option value="8136">ARCHULETA JR, DANNY W.</option>
            <option value="8166">FELICIANO, ANA J.</option>
            <option value="8167">FRASER, MARY K.</option>
            <option value="8169">KING, THERESA M.</option>
            <option value="8217">ALNWICK, ANDREA L.</option>
            <option value="8221">THOMPSON, LINDONA J.</option>
            <option value="8248">GIDEON, DERON L.</option>
            <option value="8253">KEITH, TRUDI K.</option>
            <option value="8268">FREEMAN, WINDOLL M.</option>
            <option value="8285">HILL, CRAIG B.</option>
            <option value="8306">GREEN JR., CHARLES E.</option>
            <option value="8336">BENNETT, JAMES R.</option>
            <option value="8347">MARCUS CALHOUN, ATHENA K.</option>
            <option value="8392">JOHNSON, MELANIE L.</option>
            <option value="8399">FLORA, ANTHONY R.</option>
            <option value="8516">BUDDINGH, SUSANNE E.</option>
            <option value="8517">GRAY JR, JAMES J.</option>
            <option value="8556">BAKER, JEANNE V.</option>
            <option value="8567">BOOKER, GREGORY E.</option>
            <option value="8596">MATTHEWS, TRANESSA T.</option>
            <option value="8615">BUTLER, LESLIE E.</option>
            <option value="8617">KOCH, ALESIA R.</option>
            <option value="8618">PATRI, TERI L.</option>
            <option value="8620">THOMPSON, RICKY</option>
            <option value="8624">NELSON, CHRISTINE A.</option>
            <option value="8665">BACK, LEONARD M.</option>
            <option value="8668">MOTEN, YASEEN</option>
            <option value="8669">OSTROWSKI, MARTIN J.</option>
            <option value="8691">SWANSON, KATHLEEN</option>
            <option value="8779">CARTER JR., IRVING D.</option>
            <option value="8782">MICHAELS, JON</option>
            <option value="8818">TAYLOR, SHEILA D.</option>
            <option value="8872">BARRY, MARISELA</option>
            <option value="8877">LONG, JONATHON C.</option>
            <option value="8898">CRAMPTON, PAULA V.</option>
            <option value="8899">HAROLD, WILLIE R.</option>
            <option value="8900">MCGEE, KRISSY M.</option>
            <option value="8951">HODGES, ANGELA L.</option>
            <option value="8952">KNIFFEN, SHARRON A.</option>
            <option value="8953">MALDONADO, LYNDA A.</option>
            <option value="8954">NARTATES, TINA M.</option>
            <option value="8961">FRANK, MARY E.</option>
            <option value="9001">GRIEGO, TANYA M.</option>
            <option value="9012">MALDONADO, RANDY</option>
            <option value="9062">BRIELS, ROBERT W.</option>
            <option value="9089">ERFORT, LORRAINE M.</option>
            <option value="9090">HUNTER, DEBRA A.</option>
            <option value="9111">CRANDALL, ROBERT E.</option>
            <option value="9114">SHAW MAINARDI, BARBARA</option>
            <option value="9115">WHITFORD, CYNTHIA E.</option>
            <option value="9143">DIAZ, ONAILYN</option>
            <option value="9160">BARON, DONNA J.</option>
            <option value="9161">BURKE, STACEY J.</option>
            <option value="9162">GRIGSBY, DEBORAH L.</option>
            <option value="9164">STEWART, JOHNNIE B.</option>
            <option value="9178">LEATH, NICHOLAS D.</option>
            <option value="9187">ALEXANDER, SIMON R.</option>
            <option value="9191">THIEL, MELISSA J.</option>
            <option value="9203">MARTINEZ JR., DANIEL A.</option>
            <option value="9205">RODRIGUEZ, RUBY</option>
            <option value="9230">MEHALKO, JESSICA M.</option>
            <option value="9232">BROCK, STEPHEN A.</option>
            <option value="9236">THOMPSON, DIANE</option>
            <option value="9269">ALVAREZ, JESSE R.</option>
            <option value="9272">COURTS, LAMETRA Y.</option>
            <option value="9275">VOUGHT LAINE, MARILYN J.</option>
            <option value="9288">FREEMAN, AMELIA K.</option>
            <option value="9290">LENOX, DIANE E.</option>
            <option value="9309">NATION, CINDY S.</option>
            <option value="9314">RATH, SHAWN C.</option>
            <option value="9316">SMITH, KEITH P.</option>
            <option value="9350">CALDWELL, RENEE M.</option>
            <option value="9351">CLAIBORNE JR., DAVID N.</option>
            <option value="9354">PARKER, NICOLE D.</option>
            <option value="9355">TABOR, MEGAN M.</option>
            <option value="9375">GOMES, MELANIE</option>
            <option value="9387">FENNELL, BRITTNEY L.</option>
            <option value="9388">GONZALEZ, ELENA O.</option>
            <option value="9389">JOHNSON, RUTHIE M.</option>
            <option value="9398">CHRISTENSEN, DANIELLE M.</option>
            <option value="9399">DEFALCO, MARC L.</option>
            <option value="9400">EDWARDS, MATTHEW L.</option>
            <option value="9401">MORTON, TANGIA J.</option>
            <option value="9421">RICE, NANCY M.</option>
            <option value="9428">BARRETT, TERRI D.</option>
            <option value="9433">RISTICK, CHRISTOPHER N.</option>
            <option value="9434">STARK, RICHEY T.</option>
            <option value="9444">ALVAREZ, WES</option>
            <option value="9445">FENNELL, BREANNA L.</option>
            <option value="9451">BABER, RENEE L.</option>
            <option value="9453">PACCIONE, JENNIFER M.</option>
            <option value="9468">PAHL, NICHOLAS J.</option>
            <option value="9470">SPRUIELL, CHRISTINA E.</option>
            <option value="9481">JOHNSON, CHARLENE</option>
            <option value="9482">LEWIS, BARBARA M.</option>
            <option value="9531">DILLERY, DENISE R.</option>
            <option value="9533">HOLTER, LINDA S.</option>
            <option value="9552">BARNES, JEFFREY R.</option>
            <option value="9554">ESPINOSA, ALEXANDER D.</option>
            <option value="9555">SAN NICOLAS, JAMES R.</option>
            <option value="9564">ELLIS, SUMMER M.</option>
            <option value="9565">FREEMAN, DENISE F.</option>
            <option value="9566">SHERMAN, SYBIL M.</option>
            <option value="9578">SARMIENTO, DAISY</option>
            <option value="9579">VILLA, RICARDO A.</option>
            <option value="9580">BOHN, ANN E.</option>
            <option value="9581">HAMILTON, MARIE A.</option>
            <option value="9582">LITTLE, JOANNE</option>
            <option value="9583">THOMAS, KORYN A.</option>
            <option value="9588">ALVARADO, MARIO A.</option>
            <option value="9589">MARCELLI, LYNN A.</option>
            <option value="9590">VICKREY, JOSHUA D.</option>
            <option value="9607">ROBINSON, MARIE</option>
            <option value="9608">THOMAS, CRISTOPHER L.</option>
            <option value="9609">WILLIAMS, LASHAWN M.</option>
          </select>
        </span></p>
      <p><span style="font-family: Arial;">&nbsp; <input onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this schedule?  All submissions are final!');return false ;" value="Submit Schedule" type="submit"></span> <br>
      </p>
    </big></div>
  <big> </big>
  <p><big><iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?height=290&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=gku5gu8cmidp7170l2j0gio11k%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23B1365F&amp;ctz=America%2FLos_Angeles"

        style="border-width:0" scrolling="no" height="290" frameborder="0" 
width="610"></iframe>
    </big></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define "output correctly"? What are they doing now? What should they be doing? Since it seems to basically be self contained, it'd also be really helpful if you got it working in SO's code snippet tool so it can be run directly.

Comment: The output goes into a file, the issue is, it doesn't seem to matter what you select, it always outputs the exact same schedule.

Comment: Is this complete code? you mentioned the output goes into a file? don't see that code. complete code helps.

Comment: The code is complete, on submit, it creates a simple txt doc, with the schedule, in theory.  I had this working fine in a 2 week format, with no table, but i broke it somehow making it a 31 day, and putting it in a table.

Comment: I figured it out, I needed to have a better naming convention for the radio buttons rather than just numbers, changing the name for them to 1st, 2nd, etc, fixed it, thanks everyone for looking.

Comment: cool. also, change this statement pom.style.display = 'none'; to 'hidden'.